# matching substring to a list of strings faster

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, data-structures

I've seen a common string parsing scenario in my org and was wondering if there's a better way to achieve it, it goes something like this -

I've got an input string that represents a `filename+ext` eg. `abc.txt`, `abc.2.out`, `abc.txt.temp`, etc) and I've to extract the filename from it.

I also have list of all valid extensions (like `.out`, `.exe`, `.txt.temp`, `.txt`) with me.

I sort this list in descending order by `string::size()` such that bigger extensions are matched first and it doesn't end up eager to match similar shorter extensions.

Please note that having a `.` doesn't mean it's an extension as filenames can also consist of many of these for our case. At the end of processing, I just want a separate name and extension.

Its currently implemented by iterating over the extension list and checking `input_string.ends_with(ext)` and then erasing the extension to return the actual filename. Is there any better way to do this since that list keeps on growing...??

Extracted code -

```
vector<string> extensions {"txt","out", "exe", "txt.temp"....};
// sort them by size in desc order
sort(extensions.begin(), extensions.end(), [](auto e1, auto e2) { return e1.size() > e2.size(); });
string filename = getInput();  // hello_world.txt.temp

for(const auto& ext: extensions) {
    if(filename.ends_with(ext)) { // found }
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with how hashmaps work?

Comment: Actually a reverse-trie would probably be better

Comment: If you have the input filenames `foo.bar.txt` and `bar.txt` and both `.txt` and `.bar.txt` are in your known-extensions list then what should the output be?

Comment: Trie sounds like the easiest option, since the possible extensions are known beforehand

Comment: Better is a relative comparison.  The method presented is very easy to read and understand.  It might not be the fastest or most efficient, but even with `auto` everywhere, it is easy to follow the logic.

Comment: @Dai foo.bar.txt should match with bar.txt, that's why I'm sorting with desc size.

Comment: @Matt yes it's quite pleasant solution, but this method is kind of in a tight loop and thus I was hoping if it could be better optimized.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur how would a trie work here and how much difference would it show instead of going through a list?

Comment: @Dai I searched for reverse-trie but couldn't find any such ds. is there any other name for it or some link where I can read about it?

Comment: @NubCoder It's just a trie of file-extensions, but the strings are in reverse-order, so they go `pmet.txt.` and `tuo.` (instead of `.txt.temp` and `.out` respectively) and then you walk the trie starting with the last character in the string. To improve performance further you should use a `O(1)` approach for getting the string length so you can instantly jump to the end (IIRC `size()` is not guranteed to be `O(1)`, but `(end() - begin())` is)

Comment: @NubCoder it will be faster since you won't make any brute-force comparisons